# Show that R is a rotation of the Bloch sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation

I've shown that $$R=e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}X} = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)I - i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)X$$
Where $X$ is the matrix  $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and this would apply to any other matrix $X$ such that $X^2=I$ like the other Pauli matrices. But from this it's not clear to me that $R$ is a rotation or what the axis or angle of rotation is, and I wouldn't know where to start with the calculation suggested by the first answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680954/rotation-of-the-bloch-sphere). Is there an alternative approach I could take?

Comment: @amd Sorry I meant that $R$ is a rotation! Corrected the question. So I can check if the determinant is 1 to see it's a rotation matrix but I'm still not sure how to find the axis of rotation or angle.

Comment: Determinant equal to 1 is necessary, but not sufficient. The easiest thing to check in addition to this is that the matrix is normal: $R^*R=RR^*=I$.